# CreateWindow return null error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, win32gui

I am developing an application using the win32 api, but I have a problem. I wrote code to create a simple window and then create simple button attached to this window and finally create simple menu resource and set it to the window:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include"resource.h"


#define DEFAULT_BUTTON_WIDTH 100
#define DEFAULT_BUTTON_HEIGHT 20

HMENU Menu;
HWND Window;
HWND bCreateWall;

void WMCommand(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (lParam == (LPARAM)bCreateWall) MessageBox (Window, (LPCWSTR)"You Pressed bCreateWall", (LPCWSTR)"Congrats!", MB_OK);
    else if (wParam == ID_FILE_EXIT) PostQuitMessage(0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch(msg){
    case WM_DESTROY:PostQuitMessage(0);break;
    case WM_COMMAND: WMCommand (hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam); break;
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam));
}


int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevious, LPSTR lpCmdString,int CmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    MSG msg;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)"ME";
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox (NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error: Cannot Register Class", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR!", MB_OK);
        return (0);
    }

    //create window
    Window = CreateWindow((LPCWSTR)"ME",(LPCWSTR) "Map Editor", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,0, 0, 640, 480, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (Window == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox (NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error: Failed to Create Window", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR!", MB_OK);
        return (0);
    }

    //create button to create wall
    bCreateWall = CreateWindow((LPCWSTR)"BUTTON", (LPCWSTR)"Create Wall", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 100, DEFAULT_BUTTON_WIDTH, DEFAULT_BUTTON_HEIGHT, Window,NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (bCreateWall== NULL)
    {
        MessageBox (NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Error: Failed to Create Window",(LPCWSTR) "ERROR!", MB_OK);
        return (0);
    }


    Menu = LoadMenu (hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU));
    SetMenu (Window, Menu);

    while (1)
    {
        if (PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage (&msg);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

When this runs, the window is blank and the menu and the button aren't added.

> the method createWindow return null

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You'll need to get rid of the casts.  That only stopped the compiler from telling you that you are doing it wrong, it didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  A Unicode literal is specified by putting an L in front of the string, like `L"ME"`.  Further improve your error handling by using GetLastError() to retrieve the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, I would suggest to decide on your code formatting. It looks to me that you have used pieces of code from different sources.
If I were you I would stick with default VS formatting. One liners like this:

```
if (lParam == (LPARAM)bCreateWall) MessageBox (Window, L"You Pressed bCreateWall", L"Congrats!", MB_OK); 
else if (wParam == ID_FILE_EXIT) PostQuitMessage(0);
```

make the code very difficult to read. Why not to use blocks of code with single line for each code piece:

```
if(lParam == (LPARAM)bCreateWall) 
{
    MessageBox (Window, L"You Pressed bCreateWall", L"Congrats!", MB_OK); 
}
else if(wParam == ID_FILE_EXIT) 
{
    PostQuitMessage(0); 
}
```

Also, curly brackets are mixed and that does not help analyzing the code. Spacing between delimiters also inconsistent. Be consistent in formatting do not be sloppy; this is a part of the good programming practice.

When you run your app you can see a message box saying something but you see only a garbage characters.

Your problem is that you are compiling project set for using UNICODE characters but all string are ANSI. You merely cast ANSI string to LPWSTR and that is not enough to convert strings.
Your code fails to create button since class named "啂呔乏" you end up with using (LPWSTR)"BUTTON" does not exist.

Either convert all string to generic formatting using _T("string"), TEXT("string") or use only UNICODE strings.
Replace all (LPCWSTR) with L proceeding quoted string: L"string" and try again.